# How to prove that $\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}\cos{(2x)}\cos{(3x)}\cos{(4x)}\cdots\cos{(2005x)}dx$ is positive

Tags: integral-inequality

> show that
>   $$I=\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}\cos{(2x)}\cos{(3x)}\cos{(4x)}\cdots\cos{(2005x)}dx>0$$

This problem is my frend ask me,

**My try:**

> $$I=2\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos{(2x)}\cos{(3x)}\cos{(4x)}\cdots\cos{(2005x)}dx$$
>   and I think maybe use 
>   $$2\cos{x}=e^{ix}+e^{-ix}$$
>   $$\Longleftrightarrow \dfrac{1}{2^{2003}}\int_{0}^{\pi}(e^{2ix}+e^{-2ix})\cdots(e^{-2005ix}+e^{2005ix})dx>0$$
>   and then I can't works,and I think this is nice inequality,Thank you

By the way: I have ask my frend where is from this problem,He tell me is from mathlinks
:http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=296&t=549449&p=3252846#p3252846

Comment: The integral of $\prod_{k=2}^{n}cos(kx)$ seems to be $0$ for values of $n$ congruent to $-1, 0 \mod 4$ and a positive rational fraction of $\pi$ for $1,2\mod 4$

Comment: Hello,@Jean-Sébastien  can you post your all solution? thank you

Comment: I dont have a solution, just some computation with maple/ WA

Comment: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080802233736AAGAc5m

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Keep the integral on $(-\pi,\pi)$ and use your idea of replacing each $\cos(kx)$ by $\frac12(\mathrm e^{\mathrm ikx}+\mathrm e^{-\mathrm ikx})$. This yields
$$
2^{2004}I=\int_{-\pi}^\pi\prod_{k=2}^{2005}(\mathrm e^{\mathrm ikx}+\mathrm e^{-\mathrm ikx})\,\mathrm dx.
$$
Expanding the product in the integral yields a linear combination of $\mathrm e^{\mathrm inx}$ for $n$ integer, and this linear combination has nonnegative integer coefficients. Now, for every integer $n$,
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi\mathrm e^{\mathrm inx}\,\mathrm dx=2\pi\,\mathbf 1_{n=0},
$$
hence $2^{2004}I$ is $2\pi$ times the coefficient of $\mathrm e^{\mathrm i0x}$ in the expansion of the product. This coefficient is the size of the set $S$ of $(x_n)$ in $\{-1,+1\}^{2004}$ such that $2x_2+3x_3+\cdots+2005x_{2005}=0$.

Finally, either $S=\varnothing$, then $I=0$, or $S\ne\varnothing$, then $I=2\pi\cdot\#S/2^{2004}\geqslant2\pi/2^{2004}\gt0$. Since $2005-1=4\cdot501$ is a multiple of $4$ and $n-(n+1)-(n+2)+(n+3)=0$ for every $n$, the sequence $1(-1)(-1)1$ repeated $501$ times is in $S$, hence $I\gt0$.

The argument works replacing $(2,3,4,\ldots,2005)$ by any $(n+1,n+2,\ldots,n+4k)$.

**Edit:** The change of variable $x\to x+\pi$ and the remark that $\cos(n(x+\pi))=(-1)^n\cos(nx)$ for every $n$, shows that the analogue of $I$ based on $(n+1,n+2,\ldots,n+i)$ is $0$ when $ni+\frac12i(i+1)$ is odd. In the question $n=1$ hence $I=0$ when $\frac12i(i+3)$ is odd, that is, for every $i$ such that $i=2\pmod{4}$ or $i=3\pmod{4}$ (this was observed by @Jean-Sébastien in a comment).

When $i=0\pmod{4}$, $I\gt0$ by the above.

When $i=1\pmod{4}$, note that the five first cosines can be grouped along the signs $+2+3-4+5-6=0$, and each group of four after them along the usual signs $+--+$. This yields $I\gt0$ for $n=1$ and every $i=1\pmod{4}$, $i\geqslant5$ (also observed by @Jean-Sébastien), except that $I=0$ when $i=1$.

Comment: Hello,@Did,what is $2\pi 1_{n=0}$?Thank you

Comment: and why $2x_{2}+3x_{3}+\cdots+2005x_{2005}=0$?

Comment: $1_{n=0}=1$ if $n=0$, $1_{n=0}=0$ if $n\ne0$. // To simplify, look at $\cos(x)\cos(2x)\cos(3x)$. Forgetting a division by 8 this is $(u^1+u^{-1})(u^2+u^{-2})(u^3+u^{-3})$ with $u=\mathrm e^{\mathrm ix}$. Expand this. The result is a combination of $u^n$ for $|n|\leqslant6$. How to obtain a constant term? By choosing three $\pm$ such that $u^{\pm1\pm2\pm3}=1$, that is, such that $\pm1\pm2\pm3=0$. There are two solutions ($++-$ and $--+$) hence the coefficient of $u^0=1$ is $2$. And, behold, $\cos(x)\cos(2x)\cos(3x)$ is $1/8e^{-2ix}+1/8e^{2ix}+1/8e^{-4ix}+1/8e^{4ix}+1/8e^{-6ix}+1/8e^{6ix}+1/4$.

Answer (score 0):

**Idea:** Note that when you have a polynomials $p(x)$, we have $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi p(e^{it}) \cdot e^{-n\cdot it} dt = \int_0^{2\pi} p(e^{it}) \cdot e^{-n\cdot it}dt = 2\pi \times [x^n]\{p(x)\} $$
where $[x^n]\{p(x)\}$ is the coefficient of $x^n$ in $p(x)$.

Comment: But I think following is very ugly,But thank you all the same

Comment: With this (after clearing denominators), your problem reduces to checking whether the coefficient of $x^{2011014}$ in $p(x) = (x^{2\times 2} + 1)\ldots (x^{2\times 2005} +1)$ is not zero. In other words (since when expanding all terms are positive), is there a $S\subseteq\{2,\ldots,2005\}$ such $2\sum_{s\in S} s = 2011014$ ?